# jquery ui draggable constrain ina axis x and given coordinates

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i have

```
<style>
.container { position:relative; width:600px; height:400px; overflow:hidden; }

.div-inner { position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:7200px; cursor:e-resize; }

</style>
```

$(".div-inner").draggable({ axis: "x" });

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="div-inner">Drag me!</div>
     </div>
```

i want to constrain the movement to the left and to the right of 7200 pixels width of the div inner.

if it was a scrollable element i would let it scroll from left:0px; to left: (7200-600)px;

How can i do it with draggable?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
 $(".div-inner").draggable({ axis: "x",

    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.position.left>0)
        {   
        //alert('Return back');
        $(".div-inner").animate({"left": "0px"}, 600);
        }
        else if(ui.position.left<-6800)
        {
            $(".div-inner").animate({"left": "-6400px"}, 600);
        }                                                   
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Seems like with a library that's been around as long as jQueryUI has this should be part of the API.

Comment: BTW, in my experience this code doesn't seem to be compatible with the [_containment_](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) option of the draggable API (jQuery UI 1.10.3). When you have the containment option set along with this code the content will just jump back and forth from beginning to end.

Comment: really? Thank for the heads up! This is used in previous release.

Answer (score 3):

There are several examples of constrained movement available in the jQuery UI documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/constrain-movement.html

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ axis: "y" });
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ axis: "x" });

    $( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false });
    $( "#draggable4" ).draggable({ containment: "#demo-frame" });
    $( "#draggable5" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
});
```

You can both contain draggables to  'parent', 'document', 'window', [x1, y1, x2, y2], an element or a selector. You can additionally allow only x or y axis movement.

Comment: i have read the jqueryui documentatio and i cannot make it work.
The first step is to constrain x axis as i did.
Maybe something with [x1, y1, x2, y2] will work but i haven't managed to make it work. Thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: I'm not quite certain why your container is smaller than your inner element's width. Is something like http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/zdJws/ what you're looking to accomplish?

Comment: No my purpose is to have a viewport where inside is the draggable info. Imagine that the container is a time window which has inside all days events like a timeline. The container is small so i can drag th information inside.

[=============[<-Current view->]================================]